# iOS String Converting to JSON

Tags: json, parsing, ios

I am a noob at this and I apologize for the simple question but I looked everywhere and have not found any answers to my problem. Is there any way to parse a string in iOS to JSON? Particularly for the iPhone.

So far I have managed to download the JSON API for iPhone and parsed JSON. But that is as far as I got.

I apologize for my english if I sound vague or not straight to the point.

Comment: Which JSON library are you using? There are quite a few available for iOS: http://cocoaobjects.com/?s=json

Comment: Also, paste the code you’re using to parse the JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

TouchJSON is available @ https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

Use TouchJSON Writer class to create JSON File as using this class JSON can be created from dictionary and array.

Comment: Your link is to JSON Framework. TouchJSON is at https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON . Different libraries, either of which would satisfy the OP's need. I tend to prefer JSON Framework, just because I find the interface a touch more convenient, but both have plenty of users and fans.